# Can infopath be integrated with asp.net for the data entry portion of an application?

Tags: infopath

Can ms infopath be integrated with asp.net or is it only for use with sharepoint? I would use it to provide the dataentry portion of an c# aspnet application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an infopath form with code to feed data to a web service, I suppose... but why not just make a web form to do the task?  Think about what benefits an Infopath form would provide in this scenario.